# Views Grouping by Taxonomy Parent of a Parent

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm working with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to build a display that groups by "Categories" - see the example- in a vocabulary. I had that working just fine when the vocabulary only went one level deep.

Now what I need to do is add another level into the Vocabulary. The problem is that when I do that, it's grouping things I don't want grouped.

The Example:

```
Models
- Category 1
    - Model Alpha
        - Build 1
        - Build 2
        - Build 3
    - Model Beta
- Category 2
    - Model Charlie
        - Build 1
        - Build 2
    - Model Delta
        - Build 1
        - Build 2
- Category 3
    - Model Echo
    - Model Foxtrot
```

The trouble is when I group by fields and select "(Parent) Taxonomy Term Description" it's grouping by my "Category" description and my "Model" description. I only want them grouped by "Category".

I was hoping there was an option for a depth selection and maybe that would help, but I can't get views to show any term with a depth selection outside of the contextual filters section.

Any ideas or for things like this are we really just stuck with a two level taxonomy?